# Android Clip image to bounds

Tags: android, shapes

I have a custom `@drawable` as a background for a button. I have a bitmap and a shape on top of it. The problem is that the corners of the bitmap are not clipping to the shape, like illustrated bellow.

My question is: Is there a way to clip the bitmaps to the bounds the shape? How?

[image]

**EDIT:** Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#8F8F8F" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#8f8f8f" />
            <corners
                android:radius="8dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <!-- <nine-patch android:src="@drawable/button"/>-->
                <bitmap android:src="@drawable/background_image" />
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
                    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#8f8f8f" />
                    <corners android:radius="12dp" />
                    <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your issue. Can you provide code (xml or java)?

Comment: You guys are right. I had it in mind to post the XML, but forgot along the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to change alpha level at the corners or use [Draw 9-patch tool](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) to create the background